# Haskell, Snap: Simple snaplet construction. When do we use snaplet and when library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am trying to understand simple snaplet construction.
Also, when do I actually need to make a snaplet and when a simple side library?
And if I do need one how do I make it out of a library?

For example, I have a bunch of DB functions where I wrap my SQL code like below.

```
data Person = Person {personName :: ByteString, personAge :: Int}

connect :: IO Connection
connect = connectSqlite3 "/somepath/db.sqlite3"

savePerson :: Person -> IO ()
savePerson p = do
c <- connect
run c "INSERT INTO persons (name, age) \
      \VALUES (?, ?)"
      [toSql (personName p), toSql (personAge p)]
commit c
disconnect c
```

Every function initiates a new connection and closes the connection after commit.
I guess making a snaplet is the way to avoid connection in every function?
In my handler I would use it like this:

```
insertPerson :: Handler App App ()
insertPerson = do
  par <- getPostParams
  let p = top par
  liftIO $ savePerson p
where
  top m =
    Person {personName = head (m ! (B.pack "name"))
           ,personAge  = read (B.unpack (head (m ! (B.pack "age")))) :: Int
           }
```

It works so far. My question(s) is/are:
When do I actually need to turn a library into a snaplet? Do I need to turn my simple DB library into a snaplet just to initialize the connection instead of making the connection in every function?

Now, If I make the snaplet ...
On the Snap website there is a tiny example of a top level sanaplet but there is no trace of how to make simple pluggble snaplet of your own.

So I added snaplet initialization function to my DB library

```
dbInit :: SnapletInit b Connection
dbInit = makeSnaplet "DB" "My DB Snaplet" Nothing $ do
  dbc <- liftIO $ connectSqlite3 "/somepath/db.sqlite3"
  onUnload $ disconnect dbc
  return $ dbc
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? Is this all I need to turn it into a pluggble snaplet?

Then I stack this DB snaplet into the main app

```
data App = App
  { _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App),
    _dbcon :: Snaplet (Connection)
  }

makeLens ''App

app :: SnapletInit App App
app = makeSnaplet "app" "My app" Nothing $ do
  h <- nestSnaplet "heist" heist $ heistInit "templates"
  d <- nestSnaplet "" dbcon dbInit
  addRoutes routes
  return $ App h d
```

Now, all I gain is the connection available to my request handlers, right?
So my handler becomes:

```
insertPerson :: Handler App App ()
insertPerson = do
  par <- getPostParams
  let person = top par
  connection <- gets _dbcon
  liftIO $ savePerson connection person
where
  top m =
    Person {personName = head (m ! (B.pack "name"))
           ,personAge  = read (B.unpack (head (m ! (B.pack "age")))) :: Int
           }
```

This does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to extract the connection from the snaplet handle (dbcon)? Is this generaly the correct direction to construct a simple snaplet? Do I actually need a snaplet here in my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Handler` is an instance of `MonadState`: `MonadState v (Handler b v)`.

`Handler` is also an instance of `MonadSnaplet` and therefore provides the `with` method:
`with :: Lens v (Snaplet v') -> m b v' a -> m b v a`

`dbcon` is a `Lens App (Snaplet Connection)`.

So to get to the `Connection` we can use:
`conn <- with dbcon get`

You would normally create a snaplet if you were providing functionality that everyone might benefit from. In your case, it's probably best to take advantage of the [HDBC snaplet](https://github.com/norm2782/snaplet-hdbc), which you can use to connect to a sqlite3 db.

Checkout http://norm2782.github.com/snaplet-hdbc.html for a good tutorial on using the HDBC snaplet.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen the HDBC snaplet and I've played with it. I want to do it myself from scratch, this is the only way to learn for me. First I tried to work out how to use a simple library within my handlers and now I want to learn how to construct  a snaplet oput of it. I want to understand how a simple snaplet is constructed, how they interact and why/when I need one ...

Comment: Can you tell me if this is the correct direction to construct a snaplet? Is the dbInit all I need?

Comment: @r.sendecky As a very simple snaplet, I would say it's fine.  However snaplets are normally used to run actions from a monad you've created.  In your case it works because you just use IO actions.  I recommend analyzing mightybytes [AcidState snaplet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snaplet-acid-state/0.2/doc/html/src/Snap-Snaplet-AcidState.html#Acid). It's a good example of how/why to construct a snaplet.

Comment: I need more explanation, if anybody can do it for me:

If i have my app state like this

    newtype App = App
      { _connectionPool :: Pool Connection
      }

    makeLenses ''App


how i can get my connection pool inside request handler?

    createListHandler :: Handler b v ()
    createListHandler = do
      pool <- iWantGetMyPoolHere

Do i have to use Snaplet (Pool Connection) instead of Pool Connection in my app state?